# How to fetch the selected dropdown values in the editable form in the dropdown using django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Dropdown value is stored in separate table,how to retrieve the dropdown value in the editable form

views.py

```
def edit(request, id):
        form = DeptForm(request.POST)
        form1 = DesigForm(request.POST)
        dt = Department.objects.all()
        dg = Designation.objects.all()
dept = request.POST.get("depart")

        Department.id = dt
        desig = request.POST.get("design")

        Designation.id = dg
        print(Designation)
        edit_record = Emp_Profile.objects.get(pk=id)
        print(edit_record)
        context = {
                'edit_record': edit_record
       }
        print(context)
        print(edit_record.department)
        return render(request, 'registration/register_edit.html', context,{'form' : form, 'form1' : form1})

def update(request, id):
        form = DeptForm(request.POST)
        form1 = DesigForm(request.POST)
        dt = Department.objects.all()
        dg = Designation.objects.all()


        if request.method == "POST":

                First_name = request.POST['First_name']
                lname = request.POST['lname']
                depart = request.POST.get("depart")
                Department.id = dt

                print(depart)
                uname = request.POST['uname']
                design = request.POST.get("design")
                Designation.id = dg
                print("design")
                print(design)
                mnumber = request.POST['mnumber']

                Emp_Profile.objects.filter(pk=id).update(
                        first_name=First_name,
                        last_name=lname,
                        Mobile_Number=mnumber,
                        username=uname,

                )

                return redirect('/accounts/profile/')
        return render(request,'register_edit.html',{'form':form, 'form1':form1})
```

In this department and designation is two separate table,while storing it is stored in another table called "Emp_Profile".while editing,the selected value of department and designation should come with dropdown.

Comment: why do you have two views? one view should handle both GET and POST. Also you're not showing your forms. But if they are `ModelForm`, then you can pass the instance you are editing to the form, so that all the fields are pre-filled with the current values, including your dropdown. Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/): first fetch the instance (`edit_record`) then create the forms `DeptForm(request.POST, instance=edit_record.department)`